# How to build nginx-upstream-module in docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-upstreams, upstream

When I am trying to build nginx-upstream-module in docker container, I got following error.

> ./config: line 13: auto/have: No such file or directory

Can anyone help me, how to build nginx-upstream-module in docker container or
what is meant by the above error and how to resolve this.

What is auto/have in the nginx-upstream-module config file.

I am running the above command in cd c: nginx-upstream-module directory with administrator privileges.

Comment: move the configure to your nginx directory and try

Comment: Please add you `Dockerfile` and your project hierarchy